# Clickable Map Grid Overlay

Tags: grid, maps, overlay, tiles

I am trying to create a map grid using Google maps. I have a fixed border frame and need to create an overlay on top, similar to [this](http://www.mappingsupport.com/p/gmap4.php?ll=39.626861,-104.942131&t=t1&z=10&coord=utm) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTJaQ.png) example. However, I also need to be able to hover over map tiles using the mouse cursor and change the hue/saturation of the overlay elements accordingly. Each element in the grid will have an onClick() event associated with it.

After some research I found libraries that can be used to draw a grid such as OSMatrix.I also noticed that one of the d3.js [examples](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084) is somewhat similar to what I am aiming to achieve. The question is, how can I add the visualization as an overlay on top of a map and is it possible to accomplish with API v3 and JavaScript?